# C# WPF: Add item from ComboBox to Access DB

Tags: oledbconnection

I'm trying to figure this out for the last few days. I have a form with DO/SEE/EXPECT in a form with TextBoxes (this works), but when I try to add a ComboBox with 3 items, I always get an OleDbException on **cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();**:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Configuration;

namespace WpfApplication3
{

    public partial class Records : Window
    {
        public Records()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    
        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ToString();
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into [tblInboxRecords](DO, SEE, EXPECT, Segment) Values (@do,@see,@ex,@sg)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@do", txtdo.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@see", txtsee.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ex", txtexpect.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sg", boxsegment.Text); // This is the combobox
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Item Inserted");
            }

        }
        
    }
}
```

And this is the .xaml for the ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="boxsegment" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="72,85,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Type A (Operator)"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Type B (Urgent)"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Type C (Critical)"/>
</ComboBox>
```

When I was searching for a solution, I could only find how to use items from your DB to WPF, but not the other way.

Comment: What's the data type of your 'segment' column? It looks like it's not compatible with `string`, so you'll have to convert `boxsegment.Text` to a compatible type if you want to use it as a query parameter.

Comment: I assume you're talking about the column in Access? I tried 'Short Text', 'Long Text' and added a value list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

By using `string SegmentBox = boxsegment.Text.ToString();`

instead of `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sg", boxsegment.Text);`